# Cannot see Graphics added to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I intend to implement a clock with secondhand, but I cannot display second hand properly.

My code shows bellow, ClockFrame new a SecondHand and pass panel to SecondHand. SecondHand is expected to get seconds and update itself. I think g2.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, null); show my bitmap, but not at all. I am really confused. Thanks in advance.

Clock.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Clock {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
      ClockFrame c=new ClockFrame();
  }
}
```

SecondHand.java

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

 public class SecondHand extends JComponent implements Runnable{

    private JPanel fpanel;
    private BufferedImage bImage;
    private Thread secThread;
    private Point center;
    double radPerSec = Math.PI/648000;
    public SecondHand(String path,Point p,Object o){
    try {
        bImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //setLocation((int)p.getX(),(int)p.getY());
    setLocation(0,0);
    center=p;
    ((JPanel)o).add(this);
    fpanel=(JPanel)o;

    secThread=new Thread(this);
    secThread.start();

}

public void run() {
   while(true) {           
          try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
                g2.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, null);
             //fpanel.repaint();

           } catch (InterruptedException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

}


}
```

ClockFrame.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClockFrame extends JFrame {

public ClockFrame(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(panel);
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    panel.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
    panel.setLayout(null);//!important
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    SecondHand sHand=new SecondHand("./res/icon/sechand.png",new   Point(450,300),panel);


  }
}
```

Comment: You did not add sHand to ClockFrame, and instead of getGraphics override paintComponent in your thread.

Comment: But I add sHand to the panel on frame. So i think i dont have to add that again on frame?

Comment: You need to add like this panel.add(sHand); and this.add(panel). If you just declare and initialize them you just create object of panel not asociated with visible frame.

Comment: I did. there is a    ((JPanel)o).add(this); in SecHand constructor.

Comment: Java is passing arguments by-value so I think that you are actually not adding the component to the right panel.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). This will help to understand, how to do a custom painting in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SecondHand` component was not appearing for two reasons:

1. It was not added to `panel`.
2. `panel` has no layout, so it would have been shown at a size of 0 x 0.

As mentioned in comments, do nut use `getGraphics()`, but instead override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. To trigger that method, use a Swing based `Timer` to call `repaint()`.
For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like as seen below. One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). Below I just create a new buffered image.

Other problems I see in the source. Every `JComponent` is an `ImageObserver` so use it instead of `null` when drawing an image. Look at the other code comments carefully for other tips.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClockFrame extends JFrame {

    public ClockFrame() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(panel);
        setSize(1000, 1000);
        panel.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
        // this is NOT the way to go
        //panel.setLayout(null);//!important
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        SecondHand sHand = new SecondHand("./res/icon/sechand.png", new Point(450, 300), panel);
        panel.add(sHand); // THIS is impoertant
        // this should be done after all components are added!
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        ClockFrame c = new ClockFrame();
    }
}

class SecondHand extends JComponent implements Runnable {

    private JPanel fpanel;
    private BufferedImage bImage;
    private Thread secThread;
    private Point center;
    double radPerSec = Math.PI / 648000;

    public SecondHand(String path, Point p, Object o) {
        try {
            bImage
                    = new BufferedImage(900, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            //ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //setLocation((int)p.getX(),(int)p.getY());
        setLocation(0, 0);
        center = p;
        ((JPanel) o).add(this);
        fpanel = (JPanel) o;

        secThread = new Thread(this);
        secThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
                g2.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, null);
                //fpanel.repaint();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for all of advice and help.

Comment: related post hits the spot, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841582/getting-the-right-image-observer-for-rotating-an-image